# unity3d, How to Set GUI.windows layer on C#? or Put Animation Sprite on Gui.Windows

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript

Object:

- Put 2D Animation(Sprite) On/Inside the GUI.Windows

I had done the Animation and GUI.Windows, at the same time i had set the Camera4GUI also. So had ready layer to use for it. but the problem is, my animation when come out will appear behind the GUI.Windows. So how i can set the GUI.Windows layer? or put the animation inside the GUI.Windows?

Because i using C# and still new on unity, so i dont know except [this way](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUI-depth.html), still got any solution or not. thanks for helping.

[image: Problem Here]

Answer (score 0):

make a seperate camera and set it to render to texture. Then use this camera to render your scene to texture. Then use GUI.DrawTexture to render it inside the window (or any other GUI way you prefer).

Comment: sorry, is that possible can show me some example? i still new on Unity. not really understand your answer. thanks a lot.